# Assistant sends fulfillment request in conversation webhook format instead of Dialogflow webook format

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I tried to build the Dialogflow fulfillment with Java SDK and integrates the agent with Google Assistant.
However, when I try it on simulator, sometimes I got the webhook request in Conversation webhook format instead of Dialogflow webhook format, often happens when I touch input in suggestion chips.

What's the reason behind that? Why my fulfillment backend aren't getting the Dialogflow webhook format instead? Any settings I could have done on the Actions console or Dialogflow? Or shall I make a new request to Dialogflow agent when I receive the conversation webook request?

Request from Assistant:

```
{
  "user": {
    ...
  },
  "conversation": {
    ...
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "TOUCH",
          "query": "瑜伽"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "瑜伽",
          "textValue": "瑜伽"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    ...
  },
  "isInSandbox": true,
  "requestType": "SIMULATOR"
}
```

Comment: Does this only happen in the simulator? If you use a physical device is it fine?

Comment: @NickFelker Both my tablet and simulator has the same issue, but I don't understand why

Comment: If you still experience this issue and you were not able to find any leads to the root cause within the [assistant community](https://developers.google.com/assistant/community), I would suggest you contact [actions-on-google support](https://support.google.com/actions-console/contact/support).